# How do I build a class that shares a table with multiple columns in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Job table

```
    public class Job
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public int SalesManagerId { get; set; }
    public int SalesRepId { get; set; }
}
```

and a Person table

```
    public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int FirstName { get; set; }
    public int LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, how do I link the SalesManagerId to the Person (or PersonId) as well as the SalesRepId to the Person (PersonId)? The Sales Manager and Sales Rep are independent of each other. I just don't want to make 2 different lists to support the Sales Manager and Sales Rep roles.

I'm new to MVC3, but it seems

```
public virtual Person Person {get; set; }
```

would be the way to go, but that doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What ORM are you using? Entity Framework / Nhibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Job class like this

```
public class Job
{
   public int JobId { get; set; }
   public virtual Person SalesManager { set; get; }
   public virtual Person SalesRep { set; get; }
}
```

This will create the Job table with 3 columns. **JobId**, **SalesManager_PersonID** (ForiegnKey) ,**SalesRep_PersonID** (Foriegn key)

Comment: @BarrettKuethen: Yes. Because we mentioned Person as the type. So EF will use the type of Primary key of Person entity